# Date format returning ORA-00904 in java code but not in sql developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using spring JDBCTemplate to query my data.

---

I have the following query in my code

```
static final String SQL = SELECT msgs.msg_submit_date MSG_DATE FROM {0}.messages msgs 
WHERE TRUNC(msgs.msg_submit_date) 
BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:endDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') ;

String formattedSQL = MessageFormat.format(SQL , new Object[] "sms.schema"});
```

and I am getting an `ORA-00904: "DD": invalid identifier` error when I run it. I am assuming this is because the `msg_submit_date` column has `HH:MI:SS` associated with it, however, I don't want to place `HH:MI:SS` in my java code. Having year, month and day will suffice.

Also, when I run the same query, in my Oracle SQL Developer IDE, it runs fine without any errors so not sure what is going wrong.

---

The date gets generated via `java.time.LocalDate` using the following format:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy");
```

which returns the following string format `2018-06-03`.

The jdbc call:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(formattedSQL, params, new MessagesRowMapper())
```

---

I think it maybe due to `MessageFormat`.

Comment: Show us your Java code. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have made the edit

Comment: The single quotes are being lost; is that really exactly how it looks, or is the entire string enclosed in double quotes? Does it need to be? (Also, why doesn't your `ofPattern()` match the `to_date()` pattern; and why are you passing strings instead of binding dates directly - doesn't Spring allow that?)

Comment: what about `formattedSQL`?  How do you pass the values? Where is the code of the row mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the query doesn't have the single quotes when it is executed; you can get the same thing with:

```
SELECT msgs.msg_submit_date MSG_DATE FROM messages msgs
WHERE TRUNC(msgs.msg_submit_date)
BETWEEN TO_DATE(:startDate,YYYY-MM-DD) AND TO_DATE(:endDate,YYYY-MM-DD);

ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00904: "DD": invalid identifier
```

The date format components are being seen as identifiers, not as part of a string.

You need to figure out why that is happening - the most likely explanation is that you don't have them in the static string in your Java code, despite what you have posted in the question, but they may be being stripped out by a later transformation, e.g. by the `MessageFormat.format()` call.

Comment: Ty. It was due to MessageFormat stripping out single quotes. Not sure why it does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as:

```
SELECT msg_submit_date
FROM messages
WHERE submit_date >= DATE '2018-06-03' AND
      submit_date < DATE '2018-06-13';
```

Then you don't need to worry about any potential time component on the value.

That said, your problem appears to be with moving the data to your application.  Perhaps this will help:

```
SELECT TRUNC(msg_submit_date)
```